# PHP fgets with if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, fgets

I have to input some codes in a .txt file like this:

- 34,bryan,ingles,23,25,30,inge,78,Aprobado Normal
- 20,jorge,math,20,20,20,lic,60,Pasa con lo minimo

now i have to use a php function to show a specific line using a search.
i was trying to us a fgets and an If statement to pull it. Like

```
while(!feof($fp)){$linea=fgets($fp, (if $code==34));echo $linea;}
```

i need the code. using a $_post to get a specific line from the .txt file if the $_post[codigo] is in .txt file and to show it.

Comment: And your question is.. ?

Comment: i need the code. using a $_post to get a specific line from the .txt file

Answer (score 1):

Your file look like a comma-separated-value file so you'd better use `fgetcsv`.

```
while (!feof($fp)){
    $linea = fgetcsv($fp);       // gets one line and cut it in each comma ( `,` ).
    if ($linea[0] == '34') {     // [0] access the first comma-separated-value of your line
      echo implode(',', $linea); // displays the line after concataining each element with a `,` 
    }
}
```

If your CSV contains empty lines, you should do another check (that the first value of your CSV line exists) :

```
if ((count($linea) > 0) && ($linea[0] == '34')) {
```

With the CSV approach, you can get each element of your line easily, for your first line :

- $linea[0] is 34
- $linea[1] is bryan
- $linea[2] is ingles
- $linea[3] is 23
- $linea[4] is 25
- $linea[5] is 30
- $linea[6] is inge
- $linea[7] is 78
- $linea[8] is Aprobado Normal

Comment: thank you. i need the code. using a $_post to get a specific line from the .txt file if the $_post[codigo] is in .txt file and to show it.